# Find $\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\frac{\sqrt[n]{1+ax}\sqrt[m]{1+bx}-1}{x};m,n\in \mathbb{Z}/\{0\},a,b\in\mathbb{N}$

Tags: calculus, limits

Find $$\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\frac{\sqrt[n]{1+ax}\sqrt[m]{1+bx}-1}{x};m,n\in \mathbb{Z}/\{0\},a,b\in\mathbb{N}$$

Is it possible to use L'Hospital's rule (form $\infty -\infty$)?

Comment: Hint: (*alternative way*) This is equal to the derivative of $f\colon x\mapsto\sqrt[n]{1+ax}\sqrt[m]{1+bx}$ evaluated at $x=0$.

Comment: Is it $\infty-\infty$?

Comment: L'Hospital's rule can be used only in case of 0/0 or ∞/∞ and it can't be used in case of ∞-∞

Comment: Hint:use finite expansion of $$\sqrt[n]{1+ax}\sqrt[m]{1+bx}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is only apparently an application of l'Hôpital, because the given limit is the definition of the derivative at $0$ of the function
$$
f(x)=\sqrt[n]{1+ax}\,\sqrt[m]{1+bx}
$$
since $f(0)=1$. Now
$$
f'(x)=\frac{a}{n}(1+ax)^{(1/n)-1}\,(1+bx)^{1/m}
+\frac{b}{m}(1+ax)^{1/n}\,(1+bx)^{(1/m)-1}
$$
so
$$
f'(0)=\frac{a}{n}+\frac{b}{m}
$$

Alternatively, you can use Taylor expansions:
$$
\sqrt[n]{1+ax}=1+\frac{1}{n}ax+o(x),
\quad
\sqrt[m]{1+bx}=1+\frac{1}{m}bx+o(x),
$$
so the limit is
$$
\lim_{x\to0}
  \frac
    {\left(1+\dfrac{1}{n}ax+o(x)\right)\left(1+\dfrac{1}{m}bx+o(x)\right)-1}{x}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Answer is $\frac{a}{n} + \frac{b}{m}$. Use what $\sqrt[n] {1+ax} \sim 1+\frac{a}{n}$ with $x\rightarrow 0$.